# LINQ ALL Method only works when there is one condition to check

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, datatable

I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` that contains some conditions that need to be checked against a `DataTable`.

E.g. If dic contains one entry like (key: "Email", value: "john.smith@gmail.com"), the following has to search for all the rows in the DataTable who have a value of Email equal to "john.smith@gmail.com".

```
var foundRows = dtContacts.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(c => dicConditions.All(kv => c.Field<string>(kv.Key) == kv.Value.ToString()));
```

This is working when we have only one condition in the dictionary. But I expected it to work for more conditions, too.

For instance, I will now want to check in the `DataTable` for everyone whose value for *FirstName* is "John" and value for *LastName* is "Smith" (case-insensitive). Even though I can see that there is a row in my `DataTable` with *FirstName* = "John" and *LastName* = "Smith", the above LINQ is not returning any value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. (Not sure why you're calling `ToString` on `kv.Value`, btw.)

Comment: Improbable... `All` of an empty `IEnumerable` returns `true`. Even written on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb548541.aspx): ***true** if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the specified predicate, or **if the sequence is empty;***

Comment: How are you making the string comparison case-insensitive?  Doesn't look to be done in that example.  Is that your problem - is it actually doing a case-sensitive check?

Comment: @evilbhonda no, I aim to do it but the first thing I want to is to have an exact match. That comes next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work also for multiple conditions(entries in the dictionary).

So the only thing that comes to my mind is that it's currently case sensitive but you explicitly asked for a case-insensitive approach:

```
var foundRows = dtContacts.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => dicConditions
        .All(kv => String.Equals(row.Field<string>(kv.Key), kv.Value, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```